# How to change toolbar location bellow ImageView in CollapsingToolbarLayout, in the middle of layout?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-toolbar, android-collapsingtoolbarlayout, android-appbarlayout

I want to build layout like the one bellow:

[image: toolbar in the middle of layout]

The default layout is something like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/appbar"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent">

        <com.google.android.material.appbar.CollapsingToolbarLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            app:toolbarId="@+id/toolbar"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways|enterAlwaysCollapsed|snap"
            app:contentScrim="?attr/colorPrimary">

             <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imageView"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="500dp"
                android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                app:layout_collapseMode="parallax"
                app:srcCompat="@drawable/lionking" /> 

             <com.google.android.material.appbar.MaterialToolbar
                android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                app:menu="@menu/my_menu"
                app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
                android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
                android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
                android:theme="?attr/actionBarTheme" /> 
        </com.google.android.material.appbar.CollapsingToolbarLayout>
    </com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>

    <androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_behavior="com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout$ScrollingViewBehavior">
        <include layout="@layout/item_nested_scrollview"/>
    </androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView>

</androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

now to change the toolbar location to be bellow the imageView I created new file with linearlayout (vertical orientation) and put Imageview and toolbar inside it, so the above code becomes like:

```
<com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
    android:id="@+id/appbar"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent">

    <com.google.android.material.appbar.CollapsingToolbarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:toolbarId="@+id/toolbar"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways|enterAlwaysCollapsed|snap"
        app:contentScrim="?attr/colorPrimary">

        <include layout="@layout/toolbar_in_middle"/>

    </com.google.android.material.appbar.CollapsingToolbarLayout>
</com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>

<androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_behavior="com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout$ScrollingViewBehavior">

    <include layout="@layout/item_nested_scrollview"/>

</androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView>
```

The LinearLayout file "toolbar_in_middle.xml" which is included in the above file is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways|enterAlwaysCollapsed|snap"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="500dp"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop"
        app:layout_collapseMode="parallax"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/lionking" />

    <com.google.android.material.appbar.MaterialToolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        app:menu="@menu/my_menu"
        app:layout_collapseMode="pin" />
</LinearLayout>
```

the layout display toolbar in the middle of layout as wanted, but the behavior does not work correctly, the ImageView doesn't work with parralax mode, also the toolbar doesn't acts as supposed to act. although there is app:layout_scrollFlags attributes for both.

- how to debug this issue, or how to soleve it?
- Another issue is about toolbar transparency, how to do it correctly?

the final goal is to build layout, its behavior smillar to layout in [Samsung weather app.](https://youtu.be/zDo0smivbgM)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As `CollapsingToolbarLayout` is basically a `FrameLayout`, child views will be placed by default at the top but you can simply set `layout_gravity` to change this behavior.
Other things look good in your layout. But some other changes are listed below that I thought you may need:

- I don't think your `colorPrimary` is transparent by default, so create a color resource to have the transparency desired in the screenshot.
- Usually `exitUntilCollapsed` flag is included as scroll flags of the collapsing toolbar.
- By default, collapsing toolbar replace a collapsing title with the toolbar title. If you don't want it set `app:titleEnabled="false"`.

So the layout would look like:

```xml
    <com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/appbar"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent">

        <com.google.android.material.appbar.CollapsingToolbarLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            app:toolbarId="@+id/toolbar"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways|enterAlwaysCollapsed|exitUntilCollapsed|snap"
            app:contentScrim="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:titleEnabled="false">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imageView"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="500dp"
                android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                app:layout_collapseMode="parallax"
                app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_launcher_foreground" />

            <com.google.android.material.appbar.MaterialToolbar
                android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
                android:background="@color/color_primary_half_transparent"
                android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
                android:theme="?attr/actionBarTheme"
                android:layout_gravity="bottom"
                app:title="Test"/>
        </com.google.android.material.appbar.CollapsingToolbarLayout>
    </com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>
```

And `color/color_primary_half_transparent.xml` would look like:

```xml
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:alpha="0.5" android:color="?colorPrimary" />
</selector>
```